# Can a compiler generate debug info based on namespace?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

It is probably a very very stupid question and I'm gambling by posting it here, but can a compiler generate debug info based on namespace?

It could be a very useful feature when working with template heavy libraries such as boost spirit (to be able to disable debug info generation for boost namespace).

Answer (score 1):

From a technical perspective, there's probably no reason a compiler *couldn't* be written to work this way.

From a practical perspective, I don't know of a compiler that works this way, and rather doubt that one exists, so even though it probably could be done, it's of little practical relevance.